# How to iterate through all rows in specific column but using letters instead col number

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Is it possible iterate through specific row and specific column in this row, but using column letter (D, G, P ...) instead number?
In the official documentation, I found a similar way :

```
for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=519, max_row=530, min_col=4, max_col=10, values_only=True):
    for cell in row:
        print (cell)
```

But I need to get data from cells not in a certain range, but from separate row tables (D, G, P. ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the parameter `values_only=False` you can access `cell` properties.

Try something like:

```py
cols = ["D","F","H"]

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=519, max_row=530, min_col=4, max_col=10, values_only=False):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.column_letter in cols:
                print (cell.value)
```

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Didn't know about the column_letter function. Thanks!